# Kendo UI DropDownList: Is it possible to disable just one option?

Tags: kendo-ui

Is it possible to disable an entry in a DropDownList?
So for example I can prevent users from selecting the "Please choose" entry.

Comment: Why don't you just remove the "Please choose" option once the user has selected a valid one?

Comment: Thanks for the solutions! I think all of the answers are correct - there are simple and less simple solutions. I give a try to just remove the "Please choose" when opening the dropdownlist - it's clean and easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a job for validation. If you have to show the unselectable entries in the dropdown do give them different css (grey them out) and as soon as value is selected take some action - validation message. Deselecting or doing any other tricks with the dropdown will confuse the user. If you have a chance do remove the items from the dropdown and do not show them if they can't be selected - as RGraham suggested. Below is an example how to validate optional label (what you asked for "Please choose") entry and how to get selected value after the change is made, this should get you going.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vojtiik/KpMk4/1/

```
// create DropDownList from input HTML element
 var ddl = $("#color").kendoDropDownList({
     dataTextField: "text",
     dataValueField: "value",
     dataSource: data,
     index: 0,
     optionLabel: "Select color...",
     change: function () {
        validator.validate();
         if (ddl.value() == 3)
         {
             console.log('Do something ?');
         }

     }
 }).data("kendoDropDownList");

 var validator = $("#color").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");
```

Answer (score 4):

Kendo currently doesn't support such functionality but this is easiest hack I found to disable an option in Kendo Dropdown.

```
$("#" + id + "_listbox .k-item")[index].disabled = true;
```

where id -> ID of your dropdown

index -> position of the element in the dropdown you want to disable.

Hope it helps. Enjoy :)

Comment: how would you gray-out that item then?

Answer (score 2):

You can disable this option through the Select-Event.

It's as simple as:

```
$('input').kendoComboBox({
    dataTextField: 'text',
    dataValueField: 'id',
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: function(options) {
                //instead, specify ajax call or get data from somewhere else
                options.success([{ id: -1, text: 'Please select' }, {id: 1, text: 'A'}]);
            }
        }
    },
    select: function(e) {
        var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
        if(dataItem.id === -1) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have to disable an option of dropdown if the user don't have authorization. I am not able to disable this option but I have removed this option. May the this code can help you.

```
   @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(i => i.CallTypeId)

                                                    .Name("CallTypeId")
                                                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
                                                    .DataTextField("MasterValueName")
                                                    .DataValueField("MasterValueId")
                                                    .Events(x => x.Open("ManageSecurity"))
                                                    .DataSource(source =>
                                                    {
                                                        source.Read(read =>
                                                        {

                                                            read.Action("GetCallType", "Common", new { Area = "" });

                                                        });
                                                    })
                                                    .OptionLabel("Select Call Type")
                                            )



 function ManageSecurity() {
            debugger;
            var result = '@TrackingHelper.CurrentUser.IsViewTestCallType';
            if (result == "False") {
                var ds = $("#CallTypeId").data("kendoDropDownList").dataSource;
                debugger;
                var elementToRemove = null;
                for (var i = 0; i < ds._data.length; i++) {
                    var element = ds._data[i];
                    debugger;
                    if (ds._data[i].MasterValueId === "335d2eae-dc47-40f7-b616-a2501b2f60bc") {
                        debugger;
                        elementToRemove = ds._data[i];
                    }
                }
                if (elementToRemove) {
                    debugger;
                    ds.remove(elementToRemove);
                }

            }
            else {
                debugger;

            }
        }
```